# ggplot with many categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a data frame :

```
df <- data.frame(z = c(2,1,2,3,2,3,2,1,1,1,3,4,1,1,2,3,4,3),
                 x = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c"),
                 cat = c("A","A", "B","B","C", "C", "A","A", "B","B","C","C","A","A", "B","B","C","C"))
```

I would like to plot in ggplot on the x-axis categorical values from x (3 categories: a,b,c).
On the y axis should be a mean value for values in "z" counted for:

```
all x="a" and cat="A"
all x="b" and cat="B"
all x="c" and cat="C"
```

Mean values (data points) coming from same "cat" should be connected and represented in 3 different colours corresponding to "cat".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(cat,x) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(z)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=avg, group=cat, color=cat)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

EDIT: if you also want an overall mean across levels of x, you can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(cat,x) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(z)) %>% 
  bind_rows(
      df %>%
      group_by(x) %>%
      summarise(avg=mean(z)) %>%
      mutate(cat="All")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # This is needed to mutate the grouping variable "cat"
  mutate(cat = factor(cat, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "All"))) %>% # Otherwise you'd have "All" between "A" and "B"
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=avg, group=cat, color=cat)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Do you know how to add one more line with an average of all "cat"?